Should we merge all programming language specific tags into a single "programming" tag?
The site has a large number of language-specific tags with only a handful of questions in each.  For example, see

java
javascript
c++
j-language
q-language
fsharp

Would anyone be opposed to merging all of these, as well as "programming-languages" into a single "programming" tag?  Since this site tends not to usually be about the programming itself (that is reserved for SO), this could help redirect questions which are specifically about some programming language for those interested in following those types of questions.

What about r tag then? It would make sense to treat it in the same way, but it's more populated right now.

@KarolPiczak R is not really so much a programming language as it is a statistical software package.  I would argue for keeping R, matlab, and potentially sas or other statistical packages as independent tags.

I think it can be good to match all of them in a single programming tag, as this site is looking to be dedicated to the "mathematical" or "theoretical" part of our jobs.
However, I believe it wouldn't be a good idea to make a difference between R, MATLAB and the other languages. My main argument is that many people will argue that they are using C# or F# to implement their models (even to test them) and that it is no different in the end than statistical languages. And I would agree with them. Anyway we'd end up having simple R or MATLAB questions.
So, I think your idea is great, let's have a "programming" tag, and let's define together what's on topic for this section.
I'd suggest:

No "best techonlogy for that?"
No trivial questions like "how do I get the SD of a portfolio in R"
Questions on very specific problems in quantitative algorithms (mainly understanding issues) are welcome
Question on behaviors of some programming language during an algorithm (efficiency, convergence time, ...) are welcome.


Seems like the best questions tagged R are only tangentially about R itself, but just include a preference for code examples in R. So I hesitate to replace those with "programming".

I would replace it. For clarity: no tags with the names of programming languages, it is not the focus of the site.

I would replace it only after going in and removing the tag from questions dealing only tangentially. Perhaps we could both go in and remove them over time (so as not to overwhelm the front page).

sure no prob. It's 11 am for me so I'll do that during the day it's fine.

Note: at least for now, I'd like to keep the r tag for questions that do deal specifically with r packages and the like. We may revisit this later.
